# Fresh Install on brand new computer, No network connectivity

Tags: networking

I'm newish to linux based, so you may have to explain like I'm 5.

my wifi card exists, I can choose my network and enter my password, but then network failed.

My ethernet exists, I can choose it, but then network failed.

I can only connect to wifi via USB tether. Please help.

Comment: Is your pc the only one getting this problem? Also try setting the IPv6 to **`ignore`** from the network connection settings.

Comment: Please show us your pc configuration and logs when you try to connect?
It'll be hard to guess the problem

Comment: Please show us your pc configuration and logs when you try to connect? It'll be hard to guess the problem